# Quoting inside "sh -c" with double quotes

Tags: bash, quoting

I'm trying to make this quoting work, but no success :

```
export perl_script='$| = 1;s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;s/Saving state/\nSaving state/'
mpv="command mpv"
mpvOptions='--geometry 0%:100%'
args=("$@")
$ sh -c "$mpv $mpvOptions ${args[*]} 2>&1 | perl -p -e $perl_script | tee ~/mpv_all.log"
syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
sh: 1: =: not found
sh: 1: s/n/r/g: not found
sh: 1: s/Saving: not found
```

So I tried this :

```
$ sh -c "$mpv $mpvOptions ${args[*]} 2>&1 | perl -p -e \"perl_script\" | tee ~/mpv_all.log"
Unknown regexp modifier "/h" at -e line 1, at end of line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Quoting is such a pain in the neck.

Comment: You probably want single quotes, like `sh -c "$mpv ${args[*]} 2>&1 | perl -p -e '$perl_script' | tee ~/mpv_all.log"`.  Why does everything need to be inside `sh -c`?

Comment: @jw013 Because, then I want to use `nohup sh -c ....`

Comment: @jw013 Can you please convert your comment into an answer ?

Comment: My comment was just a quick and dirty suggestion to get you going since all it took was adding two keystrokes. The two answers that have been posted are both far more robust than my comment and I would recommend using one of them instead.

Comment: @jw013 I like "your quick and d.... suggestion" because it solved my pb. without having to rewrite anything in my code, that's why I'd like yout to convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you meant:

```
export perl_script='
  $| = 1;
  s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;
  s/Saving state/\nSaving state/'

mpv=(command mpv)
args=("$@")
sh -c '
  "$@" 2>&1 |
    perl -p -e "$perl_script" | tee ~/mpv_all.log
 ' sh "${mpv[@]}" "${args[@]}"
```

Or if you wanted to embed the content of all those arguments as shell code:

```
shquote() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -v q=\' '
    BEGIN{
      for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        gsub(q, q "\\" q q, ARGV[i])
        printf "%s ", q ARGV[i] q
      }
      print ""
    }' "$@"
}

perl_script='
  $| = 1;
  s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;
  s/Saving state/\nSaving state/'

mpv=(command mpv)
args=("$@")

sh -c "
  $(shquote "${mpv[@]}" "${args[@]}") 2>&1 |
  perl -p -e $(shquote "$perl_script") | tee ~/mpv_all.log"
```

Where `shquote` quotes its argument in `sh` syntax (wraps arguments inside `'...'` and change `'` to `'\''`).

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you don't have to bother about what the calling shell does to the string which is the in-line shell script.  You can use single quotes around the in-line script and pass the needed argument to in on its command line:

```
perl_script='$| = 1;s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;s/Saving state/\nSaving state/'

sh -c 'p=$1; shift
       command mpv "$@" 2>&1 |
       perl -pe "$p" |
       tee "$HOME/mpv_all.log"' sh "$perl_script" "$@"
```

Comment: Actually, I would but I have another `mpvOptions` variable.

Comment: @SebMa Not in the code in the question...

Comment: You're absolutely right, I had forgotten it. I've just updated my question with it